# Got an error that attribute value is missing

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have base class that have an Url url without instantiation, than I have and class that inherit it and in the before method of it (TestNG) I have statement :

```
 url = new URL(props.getProperty(“appiumURL”));
```

the URL is 127.0.0.0
afterwards I have :

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(“automationName”, props.getProperty(“iOSAutomationName”));
String iOSAppUrl = getClass().getResource(props.getProperty(“iOSAppLocation”)).getFile();
utils.log().info(“appUrl is” + iOSAppUrl);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(“bundleId”, props.getProperty(“iOSBundleId”));
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(“wdaLocalPort”, wdaLocalPort);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(“webkitDebugProxyPort”, webkitDebugProxyPort);
//desiredCapabilities.setCapability(“app”, iOSAppUrl);
driver = new IOSDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
```

the value of the url is : http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub
than after the line of the “driver = new IOSDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);” I get an exception that the url is null,
than BuildInfo class is opened :

```
 package org.openqa.selenium;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.net.URISyntaxException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.Map.Entry;
 import java.util.Properties;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.jar.Attributes;
 import java.util.jar.JarFile;
 import java.util.jar.Manifest;
 import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;

/**
* Reads information about how the current application was built from the Build-Info section of 
the
* manifest in the jar file, which contains this class.
*/
public class BuildInfo {

private static final Properties BUILD_PROPERTIES = loadBuildProperties();

private static Properties loadBuildProperties() {
Properties properties = new Properties();

Manifest manifest = null;
JarFile jar = null;
try {
 URL url = BuildInfo.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
 File file = new File(url.toURI());
 jar = new JarFile(file);
 ZipEntry entry = jar.getEntry("META-INF/build-stamp.properties");
 if (entry != null) {
  try (InputStream stream = jar.getInputStream(entry)) {
    properties.load(stream);
  }
 }

 manifest = jar.getManifest();
 } catch (
   IllegalArgumentException |
   IOException |
   NullPointerException |
   URISyntaxException ignored) {
  } finally {
   if (jar != null) {
     try {
      jar.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
       // ignore
   }
 }
}

 if (manifest == null) {
   return properties;
  }

 try {
   Attributes attributes = manifest.getAttributes("Build-Info");
   Set<Entry<Object, Object>> entries = attributes.entrySet();
   for (Entry<Object, Object> e : entries) {
   properties.put(String.valueOf(e.getKey()), String.valueOf(e.getValue()));
 }

 attributes = manifest.getAttributes("Selenium");
 entries = attributes.entrySet();
 for (Entry<Object, Object> e : entries) {
   properties.put(String.valueOf(e.getKey()), String.valueOf(e.getValue()));
    }
   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      // Fall through
   }

   return properties;
 }

   /** @return The embedded release label or "unknown". */
   public String getReleaseLabel() {
   return BUILD_PROPERTIES.getProperty("Selenium-Version", "unknown").trim();
 }

 /** @return The embedded build revision or "unknown". */
  public String getBuildRevision() {
   return BUILD_PROPERTIES.getProperty("Build-Revision", "unknown");
  }

 /** @return The embedded build time or "unknown". */
  public String getBuildTime() {
  return BUILD_PROPERTIES.getProperty("Build-Time", "unknown");
 }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
   return String.format("Build info: version: '%s', revision: '%s', time: '%s'",
    getReleaseLabel(), getBuildRevision(), getBuildTime());
 }
```

the thing is that :

```
  attributes = manifest.getAttributes("Selenium");
  entries = attributes.entrySet();
```

the attribute is null .

what I’m doing wrong?
Thank you